# updating phpbrew's cong file don't afect runtime

Tags: apache, fedora, httpd.conf, phpbrew

On fedora :

after installing phpbrew and php-7.0.8 with this commande line :

phpbrew install php-7.0.8 +default +gd +bds +apxs2

and after some httpd configuration, php 7 seem to work well

`echo "<?php echo phpinfo();?> " > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php`

-> http://localhost/phpinfo.php indicate PHP Version 7.0.8

but when i'm updating the php.ini in the .phpbrew folder, for exemple with 
"phpbrew config", and after reloading httpd service, there is no effect on the runtime environement.

Opening .phpbrew/php/php-7.0.8/etc/php.ini

changing for exemple 
upload_max_filesize = 2M
to 
upload_max_filesize = 200M

then executing 
su -c "systemctl restart httpd"

and finaly looking again at http://localhost/phpinfo.php

upload_max_filesize : 2M

i check the php.ini path indicate by phpinfo.php:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path :    /home/antoine/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.8/etc
Loaded Configuration File   : (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files :   /home/antoine/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.8/var/db
Additional .ini files parsed`

so what?

Comment: Try to turn on `error_reporting: E_ALL` to be sure, that `php.ini` doesn't have any other errors. In case, when ini contains error - default values will be used.